# Removing alpha numeric suffix in the file

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching, suffix

I have a certain lines that have IDs in 4 th column of a file that end with ':E1' (I want to remove these lines that have 4 th column specifically ending with :E1 not :E11 or :E10 s etc ). When I do a grep I get that there are 87 lines having that pattern

```
    grep "\:E1\b" File | wc -l
    87
```

However when I do

```
    sed '/:E1$/d' File > tmp
    wc -l File
    245797 File 
    wc -l tmp
    245797 tmp
```

which is same as the original file length, which indicates that the lines with pattern ending with :E1 is not getting removed. Where am I going wrong in understanding the command?
The file looks like this

```
chr1    133374  133566  ENSG00000238009:E1  -   ENSG00000238009 1
chr1    995083  995226  ENSG00000217801:E1  +   ENSG00000217801 1
chr1    1385294 1385499 ENSG00000215915:E1  +   ENSG00000215915 1
chr1    10003388    10003465    ENSG00000162441:E1  -   ENSG00000162441 1
chr1    38273332    38273352    ENSG00000197982:E1  +   ENSG00000197982 1
```

I want to delete the lines ending in :E1 in the 4 th column

Comment: In your regex `:E1$` `$` means the end of line. None of the lines end with `:E1`.

Comment: I edited it to "that the lines with pattern ending with :E1 is not getting removed"

Comment: You say " want to remove the ones specifically ending with :E1" and "I want to delete the lines ending in :E1 in the 4 th column" and "that the lines with pattern ending with :E1 is not getting removed". Which is it? Please update that question.

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: Please see my answer. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want to delete the lines ending in :E1 in the 4 th column*:

```
$ awk '$4 !~ /:E1$/' foo
$
```

Comment: It does thanks , I did the following awk '$4 !~ /:E1$/' File > tmp ;  wc -l tmp
which shows 245710 tmp ; wc -l File which shows  245797 File

Answer (score 1):

Search for `:E1` at at of line (`$`) and replace by nothing:

```
sed 's/:E1$//' File
```

Comment: Upload your file somewhere and post a link here.